# Inclusion not a cofibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

What is an example of a compact Hausdorff space $X$ and a *contractible* subspace $A\subset X$ such that $H^2(X)\ncong H^2(X/A)$?

Note that $A\subset X$ must not be a cofibration. I was thinking that $X=[0,1]^2$ and $A$ the comb space might work but I am not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $X=S^2$ and let $A$ be the complement of a point in $X$.  Then $X/A$ has only two points, and is in fact contractible.  So $H^2(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ but $H^2(X/A)$ is trivial.

Here's an example for which $A$ is closed.  Start with a sphere $S^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, and then replace a neighborhood of a point by circular waves that oscillate faster and faster as you get near the point, accumulating at an entire line segment (like a 2-dimensional version of the topologist's sine curve).  Let $A$ be the line segment where the waves accumulate and let $X$ be the union of the modified sphere and $A$.  There is no path in $X$ from a point of $A$ to a point of the sphere, so $X$ is weak homotopy equivalent to the disjoint union of the punctured sphere and $A$; in particular, $H^2(X)$ is trivial.  But $X/A$ is an ordinary sphere, so $H^2(X/A)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you start with $S^2$, remove a neighborhood of a point and replace it by circular waves that oscillate faster and faster near the point. Why does it accumulate at a line segment? What exactly is $A$?

Comment: Let's pretend that instead of $S^2$, we had $\mathbb{R}^2$ sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^3$.  What I'm doing is taking points of the form $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,\sin(1/r))$ for $r>0$.  As $r$ approaches $0$, the set of such points accumulates at the entire vertical line segment $\{(0,0)\}\times[-1,1]$.  That vertical line segment is $A$ (except we are doing all this in a little patch of $S^2$ sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^3$, rather than on $\mathbb{R}^2$ sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. The space $X$ isn't compact, but is it paracompact?

Comment: The space $X$ _is_ compact...why do you think it isn't?  Also, any metric space (in particular, any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$) is paracompact.

Comment: Right, I just noticed my mistake, I agree now on compactness. Another thing that's not yet entirely clear to me is why $X/A$ is an ordinary sphere. Could you make that a bit more explicit? And by the way, $X$ has no cohomology at all, right?

Comment: There is a map $X\to S^2$ which "flattens" all the waves and sends $A$ to a point.  This induces a continuous bijection $X/A\to S^2$, which is a homeomorphism since $X/A$ is compact and $S^2$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: $X$ has the weak homotopy type of $S^0$ (since as far as paths are concerned, it's a disjoint union of two contractible pieces).  So it has no cohomology in positive degrees, but $H^0(X)$ has rank $2$.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that there are no paths from point of $A$ to points of the sphere, but why does this imply that $X$ is weakly equivalent to $S^0$?

Comment: Consider the obvious continuous bijection $f:X\setminus A\coprod A\to X$.  Any map from a path-connected space to $X$ factors through $f$ uniquely.  It follows that $f$ is a weak equivalence.  But $X\setminus A\coprod A\cong \mathbb{R}^2\coprod [0,1]$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^0$.